# Include note inside the text

Tags: notes

I am trying to include note inside the text as shown in the attached image[image]
I tried with the following command

```
\begin{quote}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\textbf{Note} Sometimes hypotheses term is used to refer to both algorithms and hypotheses.
\end{minipage}
\end{quote}
```

It is working but I am unable to get as exact as shown in the image. How can I resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the `framed` package. I modified [this](http://www.jevon.org/wiki/Fancy_Quotation_Boxes_in_Latex) and got with something similar to what you want as below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} %frame color
\usepackage{framed} % for defining framed environment
\newenvironment{formal}{
    \def\FrameCommand{{\color{YellowOrange}\vrule width 2pt}\hspace{2pt}}
    \MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width}
    \vspace{2pt}\noindent\hspace{-7pt}\vspace{3pt}
    }{\vspace{3pt}\endMakeFramed}
\begin{document}
\begin{formal}
{\bf Note}

Sometimes hypotheses term is used to refer to both algorithms and 
hypotheses.
\end{formal}
\end{document}
```

I have no ideas if there's already a package producing the quotation style you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Yes it is working now.